# Selecting PHP variables from joined tables

Tags: php

I am still trying to learn PHP and have some issues with this code. I have a field $youtubeurl in ID_Vehicles and I am trying to output some code if that field has data in it how do I select that field with this join to output the value like the sample below?

```
   function getDealerSettings($vid)
    {
        include('db.php');
        $query = "SELECT banner, ebay_htmlcss FROM ebay_dealersettings INNER JOIN ID_vehicles ON ebay_dealersettings.did=ID_vehicles.did WHERE vid='".$vid."'";
        $result = @mysql_query($query);
        if ($result)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            return array("banner" => trim($row['banner']), "css" => str_replace(array("\n", "\t"), " ",$row['ebay_htmlcss']));
        }
        return "";
    }

    function getTemplate($vid)
    {
        $code = "";
        extract($this->getDealerSettings($vid));
        if (!empty($youtubeurl))
            $code .= "$youtubeurl";
```

Comment: Where do you declare $youtubeurl? On line number 5, you supress warnings with @, It would be better if you do a if(!$result){die("Error".mysql_error());}else{..}

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just need to add that field to your select statement:

```
  $query = "SELECT banner, ebay_htmlcss, youtubeurl FROM ebay_dealersettings INNER JOIN ID_vehicles ON ebay_dealersettings.did=ID_vehicles.did WHERE vid='".$vid."'";
```

Comment: I tried that and if (!empty($youtubeurl))
            $code .= "$youtubeurl"; is not outputting any data

Comment: I wasn't returning the value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add youtubeurl to the SELECT statement as well as ensuring it's in your return array, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't returning the value in the array return array("banner" => trim($row['banner']),"youtubeurl" => trim($row['youtubeurl']),

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily an answer, supplements my comment to the question, I couldn't find a $youtubeurl mentioned before the empty check. If the db does not return anything or the query fails, the needed error handling is also not present. I have added simple error handling to the script. the return array contains ($return_array[0]) $errflag, which can be read to see if there was an error, $errmsg is an array containing the error msg, the third element contains your return array.

```
      function getDealerSettings($vid)
        {
          $errflag=false;
          $errmsg=array();
          $return=array();

            include('db.php');
            $query = "SELECT banner, ebay_htmlcss FROM ebay_dealersettings INNER JOIN ID_vehicles ON ebay_dealersettings.did=ID_vehicles.did WHERE vid='".$vid."'";
            $result = @mysql_query($query);

if (!$result){
   $errflag=true;
    $errmsg[]="Error with db connection". mysql_error();
}else{
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
     $return = array("banner" => trim($row['banner']), "css" => str_replace(array("\n", "\t"), " ",$row['ebay_htmlcss']));
            }
$return_array=array($errflag, $errmsg, $return);
return $return_array;
        }
```